# EMACS rebinding C-spc disable highlight of selected region

Tags: emacs, elisp

EMACS 24.1.
I need to Rebind <kbd>Ctrl-space</kbd> to a custom function that:

- go to end of line
- delete trailing spaces if any
- set the Mark (as normal <kbd>Ctrl-space</kbd>)

This is my code not working:

```
(define-key global-map [?\C- ] 'my-set-mark-command)
(defun my-set-mark-command()
   (interactive)
   (end-of-line)
   (delete-char (* -1 (skip-chars-backward "\t\s")));;delete trailing spaces
   (set-mark-command nil))
```

When no trailing spaces it works normally: start to select and highlight the region.
When trailing spaces: it deletes trailing spaces, stop at end of line, set Mark but don't highlight the region.

If I remove the last command (`set-mark-command`) and I run it manually <kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-mark-command` it works.
Please can somebody help me to make this function works properly??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modification commands cause the variable `deactivate-mark` to be reset, causing the mark to be lost. In the documentation for `save-excursion` it says how to disable that behavior, by binding the `deactivate-mark` variable with `let`. You can then change the code to:

```
(defun my-set-mark-command ()
   (interactive)
   (end-of-line)
   (let (deactivate-mark)
     (delete-char (* -1 (skip-chars-backward "\t\s"))))  ;;delete trailing spaces
   (set-mark-command nil))
```

or even include the whole `let` inside a `save-excursion`.

See manual:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html#index-deactivate_002dmark-2801

Comment: Tanks very much Diego!! It works fine (I am using by months). I apologizes for the delay to accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

Diego's explained what you want to know.  I just want to note that remapping
<kbd>C-SPC</kbd> is not a good idea.  C-SPC manipulates the mark ring,
which is extremely useful.  See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html), in particular see <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>

Comment: …useful unless you're using evil-mode :Ь