# Leave region selected after emacs operation

Tags: emacs, elisp

My question builds on [this answer by Trey Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686593/emacs-adding-1-to-every-number-made-of-2-digits-inside-a-marked-region#2686690) to [this question from SyntaxT3rr0r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686593/emacs-adding-1-to-every-number-made-of-2-digits-inside-a-marked-region).

Trey proposes the following function for incrementing each two-digit number in the selected region of an Emacs buffer.

```
(defun add-1-to-2-digits (b e)
  "add 1 to every 2 digit number in the region"
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char b)
  (while (re-search-forward "\\b[0-9][0-9]\\b" e t)
    (replace-match (number-to-string (+ 1 (string-to-int (match-string 0)))))))
```

I would like to use this function for my own purposes. However, I would like to increment the numbers many times successively. The problem with the function, in its current form, is that before each invocation, I have to select the region again with my mouse.

My question is: *How can Trey's function be modified so that it leaves the region selected after invocation?* (My ultimate aim is to assign this function to a keyboard shortcut (something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>) so that I if I keep the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> keys held down, all the two-digit numbers in my selected region will continuously increase.)

By the way, I am aware of [this answer by Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815540/emacs-keep-region-selected-after-operation#815599), which suggests using `exchange-point-and-mark` to re-select a previously-selected region. However, I tried that, and it doesn't seem to help in this instance.

Comment: +1 but note that what you pasted here is not a macro but a function.  *defun* in elisp defines a function, not a macro : )   (I edited your question and changed "macro" to "function").  Note that macros in Lisp dialects are a different beast altogether : )

Comment: maybe a silly suggestion but...  Even if you don't see the selected region after the first call to your shortcut, can't you just call the method again and again?  On my system numbers keep going up and up and up with the function written as is.

Comment: Oh really? Hm, that doesn't happen for me. I highlight a region with my mouse, then I do `M-x add-1-to-2-digits`, which increments the numbers, and then I type `M-x add-1-to-2-digits` again, and this time nothing happens. What are we doing differently, I wonder?

Comment: Without the `save-excursion` added, your function will move point to the end of the region. So if initially the mark is at the start and point is at the end then the function can be repeated. But if point was at the start and the mark was at the end, then after the first call point and mark are both on the same character at the end, and so on the next call the region is empty. `save-excursion` circumvents this problem. (n.b. With the mouse, the position you click on is the mark, and the position you drag to is point.) Also note that you can use `M-x add-1-to-2-digits RET C-x z z z z z` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your function modified to use `let (deactivate-mark)` wrapped inside `save-excursion` as suggested in the answer user event_jr linked to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11080667/903943

```
(defun add-1-to-2-digits (b e)
  "add 1 to every 2 digit number in the region"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (let (deactivate-mark) 
      (goto-char b)
      (while (re-search-forward "\\b[0-9][0-9]\\b" e t)
        (replace-match (number-to-string (+ 1 (string-to-int (match-string 0)))))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind deactivate-mark to prevent it from being set see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11080667/903943

manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html#index-deactivate_002dmark-2801